# Is there a way to compare strings ignoring case in PHP Twig?

Tags: php, twig, templating-engine

I am working with a twig in PHP, and I need to add a way to filter the results. I decided to do this in the templating language by also injecting the filtering keyword. (My data fetches all categories which each contain listings, and I want to filter the listings). According to the twig documentation, there is not such a way, unless I have missed some part of the docs.

**If I use something such as:**

```php
{% if listing.name == filter %}
    ...
{%  endif %}
```

My code will not match correctly if the name is "test" and the filter is "Test". I hope to be able to gain this functionality.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Code relevant to your problem belongs directly to your question, in text form and properly formatted.

Comment: Use `|lower` for example for both names.

Answer (score 0):

Must tally the string case.

Or, other way is to create a custom filter.

First, you need to define a new twig filter in your php code. This filter will convert both the `listing.name` and `filter` to the same case (either lower or upper) before comparing them.

Example to this;

```
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('case_insensitive_equals', function ($value1, $value2) {
   return strtolower($value1) === strtolower($value2);
}));
```

In the code above, the `case_insensitive_equals` is the name of the new filter. It takes two parameters, `$value1` and `$value2`, which are the values to be compared.

After defining the filter, you can use it like this;

```
{% if listing.name|case_insensitive_equals(filter) %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Where `listing.name|case_insensitive_equals(filter)` applies the `case_insensitive_equals` filter to `listing.name` and compares the result with `filter`. If they are equal, the code inside the `if` statement will be executed.

Answer (score -2):

To expand on u_mulder's comment, the standard method is to convert both strings to lowercase (so as to avoid any unknown capitalisation in either string) and then run a comparison that checks the type as well as content.

In PHP, this looks a little like this:

```
<?php

$stringOne = 'AbcdEfg';
$stringTwo = 'Abcdeefg';

if (strtolower($stringOne) === strtolower($stringTwo)) {
    // comparison is true
} else {
    // comparison is false
}
```

Comment: the user is asking for directions to compare two strings in a Twig template, your answer is for PHP code (not for Twig templates), so this is not a good answer to the question.